# jQuery converting multiple dates into an array

Tags: jquery, date

How can I convert the following list of dates:

```
selectedDates = 
    [
      Date {Sat May 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)}, 
      Date {Sat May 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)}, 
      Date {Fri May 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)}
    ]
```

the above fates are shown in firebug.

into:

```
'05/17/2014','05/24/2014','05/30/2014'
```

I have tried using:

```
var newdates = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy', new Date(selectedDates));
```

but it just outputs NaN,NaN,NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var newdates = $.map(selectedDates, function (date) {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pG79D/)